# Save csv file with different name from revisions of gist and show the difference

Tags: python, csv, python-requests, urllib2, github3.py

i have a gist(csv format) which updates on a daily basis and contains **n** revisions. Each revision data is different from one another.

I need to know the difference between each revision so i used gist api to retrieve the revisions which can be saved in csv

My requirement:

1. **How can i download and save  each url csv i.e example.csv with a different name?**
2. **How can get each revisions difference?**

Struck here how to download the file. I tried with **urlib, request** pypackages but i couldn't figure where i am behind.Thanks

```
gist_ids = 'abc'

def main():
    gh = github3.login(
        token=os.environ.get('my_token'),
        url='  ')
    my_gist = gh.gist(gist_ids)
    for gist_commit in my_gist.commits():
        resp_str= gist_commit.get_gist().as_json()
        resp_json = json.loads(resp_str)
        resp_url = resp_json['files']['example.csv']['raw_url']
    print resp_url

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

O/p: I have 4 revisions so it displayed 4 urls `https://github.com/gist/eec70654d178a8e1fe497d0bce94e0db/raw/5c058121cc4f289773b7013208ca5c5b0d97ba33/example.csv`
`https://github.com/gist/eec70654d178a8e1fe497d0bce94e0db/raw/cfb04e18bdf18bf7ab0b708951f62d2095c49f7d/example.csv`
`https://github.com/gist/eec70654d178a8e1fe497d0bce94e0db/raw/a20174f568129df4348d355eb0d6e378db7fa646/example.csv`
`https://github.com/gist/eec70654d178a8e1fe497d0bce94e0db/raw/137c57ef411067564341d389571dab2da070c828/example.csv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're over-complicating some things. Each of the objects returned by github3.py have the information you want.

I've taken your code below and modified it slightly. To summarize

1. I removed the usage of `as_json()` since there's no point in coercing the data to and from a string. If you wanted a dictionary, you could have used `as_dict()`.
2. Next, I used the gist's commit history and used that to find the file for each revision.
3. Using the GistHistory object and the actual GistFile object, I construct your filename to save them so it they will look like `5c058121cc4f289773b7013208ca5c5b0d97ba33-example.csv`
4. Finally, I use the GistFile object to actually retrieve the file content and save it to disk

```
gist_ids = 'abc'
   
def main():
    gh = github3.login(
        token=os.environ.get('my_token'),
        url='  ')
    my_gist = gh.gist(gist_ids)
    for gist_commit in my_gist.commits():
        gist = gist_commit.get_gist()
        gist_file = [file for file in gist.files() 
                     if file.filename == 'example.csv']
        filename = '{}-{}'.format(gist_commit.version, gist_file.filename)
        with open(filename, 'wb') as fd:
            fd.write(gist_file.content())
        print filename
```

Comment: Thanks awesome . Is there any way to get gist difference between each revision through github3 or thirdparty tool. because i have 1000 csv revisions.

Comment: So the GitHub API (and by extension, github3.py) does not provide actual diffs. It provides diff statistics but no diff. A third-party tool that you could use for this is the command-line `diff`. You can also use Python's `difflib`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html